# Rename loaded requireJS file after each change

Tags: magento2.4, static-content-deploy, requirejs-config.js

I have a question about deploying JS files loaded using requirejs-config.js.

I have a third-party plugin that needs overrides. So, I built a new plugin and inside the requirejs-config.js file I added the following code:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "original/module": "New_Module/js/test"
        }
    }
};
```

I do my changes and whatever I need to do, deploy static files and finally it works. However, I need to constantly update the JS file because this is a continuous development process. My problem is that in order to do new changes, I need to override the new JS file, rename it, update the requirejs-config.js file with the new name and then redeploy static files.

Is this the default behavior?
What should I do facilitate the development process and gain some time by avoiding the renaming thing and all other operations.

PS. Even if I try to edit the deploy JS file under pub/static/... it won't show the changes in the storefront.

Comment: No it's not default behaviour. Check sign static files configuration is enabled or not. If it's enabled then, disabled it for development purpose and then check it.

Comment: Sign static files configuration is disabled.
If I enable it for example, it breaks the entire website even if I run all CLI commands.

Comment: Then, might be permission not set proper.

Comment: I have set up the permissions following this article: https://mirasvit.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-correct-permissions.html. It's not working. 

Working with requirejs-config.js included files is very difficult. Usually, I like to work within static files and refresh the page to see the changes. Once I'm ok with them, I just update the original JS file and redeploy, but it's not working in this way as well.

It is not working even if I do the changes in the original file and redeploy after. I see the changes under pub/static, but they are not visible until I change the original file name.